# Asp.net Report Viewer SRS Setup

Tags: reportviewer, report

I currently have a srs report which has a url that looks like 
http://localhost/Report_SqlExpress/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/personnel_report
I've tried using the Report viewer control to display this report by doing the following

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
                                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="400px" Width="400px"  >
                                <ServerReport 
                                ReportServerUrl="http://localhost/Report_SqlExpress" ReportPath="personnel_report" />

                             </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

but i keep getting the error

```
The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
```

The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Does anyone know of how i can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my report path needed a slash before it.
Silly me.